# Definition of the pushforward measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a map $f:X \to Y$, and two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ on $X$ and $Y$ respectively, and a measure $\mu$ on $(X, \mathcal{A})$, we can define the *pushforward measure* $f_\#\mu$ on $B \in \mathcal{B}$ as
$$f_\#\mu(B):=\mu(f^{-1}(B)).$$
I can't seem to understand the most basic property of this measure, which is that for any measurable $g$ on $Y$, we have
$$\int g df_\#\mu=\int g \circ f d\mu.$$
I think I'm missing something really obvious here.

My thought process: It suffices to prove the case for $g=1$, as we can approximate by simple functions and then apply the monotone convergence theorem. So we want to show

$$\int_{f(A)} df_\#\mu=\int_A  f d\mu,$$

where $A$ is the support of $f$. We have $\int_{f(A)} df_\#\mu=f_\#\mu(f(A))=\mu(f^{-1}(f(A)))$, and I can't see why this is equal to $\int_A  f d\mu$.

Comment: BTW, this is equivalent to the familiar "law of the unconscious statistician" $E(g(X)) = \int g(x)P(X \in dx)$ for $X$ a random variable and $g \geq 0$.

Comment: So, I think the main problem with your argument is that you set $g=1_{f(A)}$. Then, you would have $g\circ f=1_{f^{-1}(A)}$ and end with ".... why this is equal to $\int 1_{f^{-1}(f(A))}d\mu$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the most fundamental case to start with is $g = 1_E$, for some measurable subset $E$ of $Y$. Then we can compute both
$$
\int_Y 1_E(y)\, f_\#\mu(dy) = \mu(f^{-1}(E)) = \int_X 1_{f^{-1}(E)}(x)\,\mu(dx).
$$
This is all by the definitions. Now notice (check) that the function $1_{f^{-1}(E)}(x) = (1_{E}\circ f)(x)$. This observation shows that
$$
\int_Y g(y)\,f_\#\mu(dy) = \int_X (g\circ f)(x)\,\mu(dx),
$$
when $g$ is the indicator of a measurable subset of $Y$. Now, you can extend this to the case when $g$ is a simple function using linearity of integration, and to non-negative functions by approximation and monotone convergence. Finally, the identity holds for an arbitrary integrable $g$ using linearity and the decomposition of a function into its positive and negative parts:
$$
g = g^+ - g^-.
$$